# intellij Idea keeps on installing type packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea 2019.2 and whenever i am opening any node or React project my IntelliJ idea keeps on installing the type packages thus slows down other processes like editing code etc.
While for Java project it runs very smooth. I want to disable this auto installing feature of type packages but not getting any idea how to do it.[image: Installing type packages process in status bar of Intellij]

Comment: Do you have any third-party plugins installed? I'm not aware of such IDEA feature, and can't find any occurrences of this message in IntelliJ IDEA source code.

Comment: @lena I don't have any third party plugin installed.

Comment: please reproduce the issue and share your idea.log

Answer (score 6):

Actually, from that screenshot it looks like you have the Codota plugin installed - that green icon at the bottom right of the screen. It looks like Codota tries to load type packages from NPM for packages listed in your project (I'm guessing). I have the same issue where it can't find one of these packages for whatever reason and it continually tries and fails.

Comment: Thank you for this i uninstalled the plugin.Lena i totally missed this you mentioned in your reply if i have any third party plugin well give you a thums up for the resolution.

Comment: This has also been pointed out by the support page from JetBeans: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009738660-Installing-type-packages. Hey @RajanChauhan please accept this as the answer.